Is locking interrupts within an ISR allowed?
I have a device that takes in multiple interrupts from external devices and ultimately sends one interrupt signal to the ARM processor. What I have done is written a driver containing an ISR registered with the OS.
The job of the ISR is to inspect the registers to find out which external device is firing off the interrupt and then take some appropriate action before clearing the external interrupt with a register write.
One of the things that I noticed is that my RTOS provides the ability to lock and unlock all interrupts for the CPU, but all that the documentation really says is to use it sparingly.
Would it be ok to use something like that in my use case? Or is that frowned upon? What I'm envisioning is a critical region within an ISR where I read the external interrupt, pass it along, and clear it, before unlocking the interrupts for the CPU. The reason I want to do this is to prevent any sort of potential preemption even though I haven't run into any issues yet.

You prevent interrupt preemption by making your uninterruptible interrupt the highest priority.  An interrupt will not preempt itself, and will not be preempted by a lower priority interrupt or by any RTOS thread.
You would only need to block preemption in any case where timing is critical to a very high degree.  If you have higher priority interrupts that take significant time, you have assigned inappropriate priority, or are performing inappropriate work in them.
In short, if you find yourself doing this, I would question the design before asking whether it is generally OK or not.

Would it be ok to use something like that in my use case?

Not possible to say, because you have described only the part of your system that deals with this interrupt, and whether it will work or not depends entirely on what it might impact, which is the rest of the system you have not described.  It is generally ill-advised, and very seldom necessary, and often indicative of a flawed design.
Moreover, ARM devices vary in interrupt architecture and interrupt handling, and you have not been specific, but that will affect any decision or design too.

All of this is highly MCU specific.
Generally speaking, many traditional microcontrollers utilize something called maskable interrupts and can be disabled/enabled through a global interrupt mask - which is a single bit sitting in some register.
It is generally ill-advised to meddle with that bit, because it affects everything in your program and so code doing creative things with the global interrupt mask can't be safely re-used in other projects.
These kind of microcontrollers automatically set the global interrupt mask through hardware, whenever the program enters an ISR. And automatically clears it once the code leaves the ISR. This means that only one interrupt at a time can be executed.
Some MCUs, notably the Cortex M flavoured ones, have more advanced ways to set priorities and allow "nested interrupts". Also the calling convention on these is a bit special since the ABI is such that it doesn't make any difference between a regular function call called by your program and an ISR called by hardware.

Interrupts can be disabled in ISR (interrupts need to be disabled when RTOS switches tasks) to protect critical code. Of course, as you said, it needs to be used with caution and the time to disable interrupts should be as short as possible.

Not all RTOS in all architectures need to disable interrupts ever.  For example https://www.keil.com/support/man/docs/rlarm/rlarm_ar_hints_cortex.htm
